# Facebook Marketing API: You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API

Tags: php, facebook

When trying to use the Facebook Marketing API I'm getting the error "you are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.6.' even though on all code I'm using version 2.6.

This is my code: (I've got the correct values in where the # is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang = "en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title> Home </title>

</head>

<body>

    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '#',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.6'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

// Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
Api::init("#", "#", "#");

// The Api object is now available trough singleton
$api = Api::instance();


$me = new AdUser('me');
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();

print_r($my_adaccount->getData());


?>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see this error message? The API calls in your php package FacebookAds\Api may be deprecated.

Comment: What does composer have for `"require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk":  ????"
    }`? It looks like you've changed it in JS, but the PHP class you're loading is unclear from the question.

Comment: The error message is seen when I load the index php page that has the script on.

Comment: And the composer.json file is {
  "require": {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
    "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.5.*"
  }
}

Comment: I think the issue lies with my composer.json file. Where does the code"require": { "facebook/php-ads-sdk":  } etc need to be? In a separate composer.json file in the root of the project or does it need to be in the composer.json file that is in the .vendor folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on one of your comments, you are using 
`facebook/php-ads-sdk` version 2.5. As the error mentions, you should update to 2.6 from composer.

On your project's root, change composer.json where is says:

```
{
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.5.*"
    }
}
```

to

```
{
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.6.*"
    }
}
```

And reinstall your dependancies by deleting your vendor folder and re-running `$ composer install` to pull download it with the updated dependancies.

You've included `v2.6` in your JavaScript, but this will not affect anything done with PHP.

**The docs appear to be out of date** on the README on Github, but [there is an issue hinting that updating to 2.6 should solve the problem](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/issues/210).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use setDefaultGraphVersion() method in API class(Api.php) to set version of api to call.

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

// Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
Api::init("#", "#", "#");

// The Api object is now available trough singleton
$api = Api::instance();
$api->setDefaultGraphVersion("2.6");

$me = new AdUser('me');
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();
print_r($my_adaccount->getData());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem when using java to access the Facebook marketing API. At that time, I did not find the relevant jar package in the manven warehouse, and the version on GitHub was not v12.0

[Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-business-sdk/issues/356)

But later, I saw that after their jar version was upgraded to v12.0, GIT cloned a code, packaged it and put it into its own project. It was found that the request could succeed